# Using an ADSL2/2+ router with regular ADSL?

Tags: router, wireless-networking, adsl, adsl-router

I am currently looking to replace my existing ADSL wireless router with a newer model.  I have seen a lot of routers advertised as ADSL2/2+.  I understand that ADSL2 and ADSL2+ offers faster speeds over regular ADSL, however my telephone line is not currently capable of ADSL2/2+ speeds.

My question is do ADSL2/2+ routers work on regular ADSL lines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes they do. You [shouldn't have any problems.](http://forums.whirlpool.net.au/forum-replies-archive.cfm/1125343.html)

Comment: +1 bang on, ADSL2+ routers have a whole range of protocols/annexes that they support. Standard ADSL is one of them.